# How to write Arabic text in Blender VSE?

Tags: add-on, video-sequence-editor

Many non-English languages (including Arabic) are not supported. Letters and words cannot be understood. This issue lasted for a very long time and still exists. Some add-ons were made for the 3D viewport but I think they are now obsolete and may have major bugs. No addons were made for VSE at all. Arabic speakers struggled enough trying to get around this (like typing the text in an external software then, saving it as an image). This is a basic/essential function that must exist in Blender, just like any other software.

Answer (score 3):

I created this **FREE** add-on to make Blender VSE support the Arabic language.

**What the addon does:**

After you write Arabic text, you click a button to correct the shapes of the letters, and connect the letters in a proper way (according to the Arabic grammar and writing rules).

**How to use:**

1. Create a strip in VSE.
2. Write some text (It will look incorrect).
3. Click "Correct Text" button and the text will be fixed/corrected as shown.

[image]

**Video tutorial:**

It contains more info about how to install and use. You will see the add-on tested and working live.

https://youtu.be/iFeGGFd3I84

**Download Link:**

https://88k88.blogspot.com/2021/07/how-to-write-arabic-language-in-blender.html

**Source Code:**

This may be helpful for you if you're a programmer or a developer:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Arabic Text Correction",
    "author": "Michael George",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "description": "After writing arabic text, this addon corrects it",
    "doc_url": "",
}

import bpy
text_buffer = []
current_char_index = 0
arabic_chars = ['ا', 'أ', 'إ', 'آ', 'ء', 'ب', 'ت', 'ث', 'ج','ح', 'خ', 'د', 'ذ', 'ر', 'ز', 'س', 'ش', 'ص','ض', 'ط', 'ظ', 'ع', 'غ', 'ف', 'ق', 'ك', 'ل','م', 'ن', 'ه', 'ة', 'و', 'ؤ', 'ي', 'ى', 'ئ', 'ـ']
right_connectable_chars = ['ا', 'أ', 'إ', 'آ', 'ب', 'ت', 'ث', 'ج', 'ح','خ', 'د', 'ذ', 'ر', 'ز', 'س', 'ش', 'ص', 'ض','ط', 'ظ', 'ع', 'غ', 'ف', 'ق', 'ك', 'ل', 'م','ن', 'ه', 'ة', 'و', 'ؤ', 'ي', 'ى', 'ئ', 'ـ']
left_connectable_chars = ['ب', 'ت', 'ث', 'ج', 'ح', 'خ', 'س', 'ش', 'ص','ض', 'ط', 'ظ', 'ع', 'غ', 'ف', 'ق', 'ك', 'ل','م', 'ن', 'ه', 'ي', 'ى', 'ئ', 'ـ']
chars_variants_bases = [0xFE8D, 0xFE83, 0xFE87, 0xFE81, 0xFE80, 0xFE8F, 0xFE95, 0xFE99, 0xFE9D,0xFEA1, 0xFEA5, 0xFEA9, 0xFEAB, 0xFEAD, 0xFEAF, 0xFEB1, 0xFEB5, 0xFEB9,0xFEBD, 0xFEC1, 0xFEC1, 0xFEC9, 0xFECD, 0xFED1, 0xFED5, 0xFED9, 0xFEDD,0xFEE1, 0xFEE5, 0xFEE9, 0xFE93, 0xFEED, 0xFE85, 0xFEF1, 0xFEEF, 0xFE89]
chars_arabic_symbols = ['ـ', '،', '؟', '×', '÷']
chars_common = [' ', '.', ',', ':', '|', '(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}', '!', '+', '-', '*', '/', '\\', '%', '"', '\'', '>', '<', '=', '~', '_']
chars_digits = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

#some functions and/or classes are derived from the Arabic text addon.
def is_right_connectable(c):

    if c in right_connectable_chars:

        return True

    return False
def is_left_connectable(c):

    if c in left_connectable_chars:

        return True

    return False
def get_char_index(c):

    if c not in arabic_chars:   

        return -1

    return arabic_chars.index(c)
def get_char_variants_base(c):

    char_index = get_char_index(c)

    if char_index == -1:  

        return -1

    return chars_variants_bases[char_index]
def is_arabic_char(c):

    if c in arabic_chars:

        return True

    return False
def is_arabic_char_variant(c):

    if ord(c) >= 0xFE70 and ord(c) <= 0xFEFE:
        return True

    return False
def get_previous_alphabet(index, text):

    index -= 1

    while index > 0 and (text[index] in chars_common or text[index] in chars_digits or text[index] in chars_arabic_symbols):
        index -= 1

    if index >= 0:
        return text[index]
    else:
        return None
def get_next_alphabet(index, text):

    index += 1

    while index < len(text) and (text[index] in chars_common or text[index] in chars_digits or text[index] in chars_arabic_symbols):
        index += 1

    if index < len(text):
        return text[index]
    else:
        return None




def link_text(unlinked_text):

 

    linked_text = []

    previous_char = ""

    next_char = ""

    char_code = 0

    skip_char = False


    uncounted_chars = 0

    #

    for current_char in unlinked_text:

        #

        if skip_char:
            skip_char = False
            continue

        #

        previous_char = ""
        next_char = ""

        #

        chars_count = len(linked_text) + uncounted_chars

        if chars_count > 0:
            previous_char = unlinked_text[chars_count - 1]

        if chars_count < len(unlinked_text) - 1:
            next_char = unlinked_text[chars_count + 1]

  
        if current_char == 'ل':

            if next_char == 'ا':

                char_code = 0xFEFB

            elif next_char == 'أ':

                char_code = 0xFEF7

            elif next_char == 'إ':

                char_code = 0xFEF9

            elif next_char == 'آ':

                char_code = 0xFEF5

            else:

                char_code = 0

            if char_code != 0:

                if is_left_connectable(previous_char):

                    char_code += 1

                linked_text.insert(0, chr(char_code))

                uncounted_chars += 1

                skip_char = True

                continue
        
        #

        if current_char in chars_arabic_symbols:

            linked_text.insert(0, current_char)

            continue

        if current_char == '\n':

            linked_text.insert(0, current_char)

            continue

        # 

        if current_char in chars_common:
            
            previous_alpha = get_previous_alphabet(chars_count, unlinked_text)
            next_alpha = get_next_alphabet(chars_count, unlinked_text)
            
            char_pos = 0

            if not is_arabic_char(previous_alpha) and not is_arabic_char(next_alpha) and previous_alpha != '\n':
                
                while char_pos < len(linked_text) and not is_arabic_char_variant(linked_text[char_pos]) and linked_text[char_pos] != '\n':
                    char_pos += 1
            
            linked_text.insert(char_pos, current_char)

            continue

        # 

        char_code = get_char_variants_base(current_char)
        
        if char_code == -1:   # = Not an arabic character

            # 

            previous_alpha = get_previous_alphabet(chars_count, unlinked_text)
            next_alpha = get_next_alphabet(chars_count, unlinked_text)

            char_pos = 0

            # 

            if len(linked_text) > 0 and linked_text[0] in chars_digits:

                while char_pos < len(linked_text) and linked_text[char_pos] in chars_digits:
                    char_pos +=1
            
            # 

            elif not is_arabic_char(previous_alpha):

                c = chars_count - 1

                while not is_arabic_char(previous_alpha) and char_pos < len(linked_text) and linked_text[char_pos] != '\n':

                    previous_alpha = get_previous_alphabet(c, unlinked_text)
                    char_pos += 1
                    c -= 1

            linked_text.insert(char_pos, current_char)

            continue

        #

        if is_left_connectable(previous_char) and is_right_connectable(current_char):

            if is_left_connectable(current_char) and is_right_connectable(next_char):

                char_code += 3

            else:

                char_code += 1
        else:

            if is_left_connectable(current_char) and is_right_connectable(next_char):

                char_code += 2

        linked_text.insert(0, chr(char_code))

    text = ''.join(linked_text)

    return text
def swap_lines(linked_text):

    new_text = []

    current_line_start = 0

    char_counter = 0

    for c in reversed(linked_text):

        if(c == '\n'):

            new_text.append('\n')

            current_line_start = char_counter + 1

            char_counter += 1

            continue

        new_text.insert(current_line_start, c)

        char_counter += 1

    return ''.join(new_text)
def unlink_text(linked_text):

    #

    unlinked_text = []

    #

    for c in linked_text:
        if ord(c) in {0xFE8D, 0xFE8E}:
            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ا')
        elif ord(c) in {0xFE83, 0xFE84}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'أ')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFE87, 0xFE88}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'إ')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFE81, 0xFE82}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'آ')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFE80}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ء')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFE8F, 0xFE90, 0xFE91, 0xFE92}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ب')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFE95, 0xFE96, 0xFE97, 0xFE98}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ت')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFE99, 0xFE9A, 0xFE9B, 0xFE9C}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ث')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFE9D, 0xFE9E, 0xFE9F, 0xFEA0}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ج')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFEA1, 0xFEA2, 0xFEA3, 0xFEA4}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ح')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFEA5, 0xFEA6, 0xFEA7, 0xFEA8}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'خ')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFEA9, 0xFEAA}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'د')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFEAB, 0xFEAC}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ذ')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFEAD, 0xFEAE}:
            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ر')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFEAF, 0xFEB0}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ز')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFEB1, 0xFEB2, 0xFEB3, 0xFEB4}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'س')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFEB5, 0xFEB6, 0xFEB7, 0xFEB8}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ش')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFEB9, 0xFEBA, 0xFEBB, 0xFEBC}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ص')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFEBD, 0xFEBE, 0xFEBF, 0xFEC0}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ض')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFEC1, 0xFEC2, 0xFEC3, 0xFEC4}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ط')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFEC5, 0xFEC6, 0xFEC7, 0xFEC8}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ظ')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFEC9, 0xFECA, 0xFECB, 0xFECC}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ع')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFECD, 0xFECE, 0xFECF, 0xFED0}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'غ')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFED1, 0xFED2, 0xFED3, 0xFED4}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ف')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFED5, 0xFED6, 0xFED7, 0xFED8}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ق')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFED9, 0xFEDA, 0xFEDB, 0xFEDC}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ك')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFEDD, 0xFEDE, 0xFEDF, 0xFEE0}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ل')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFEE1, 0xFEE2, 0xFEE3, 0xFEE4}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'م')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFEE5, 0xFEE6, 0xFEE7, 0xFEE8}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ن')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFEE9, 0xFEEA, 0xFEEB, 0xFEEC}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ه')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFE93, 0xFE94}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ة')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFEED, 0xFEEE}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'و')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFE85, 0xFE86}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ؤ')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFEF1, 0xFEF2, 0xFEF3, 0xFEF4}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ي')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFEEF, 0xFEF0}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ى')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFE89, 0xFE8A, 0xFE8B, 0xFE8C}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ئ')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFEFB, 0xFEFC}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ا')
            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ل')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFEF7, 0xFEF8}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'أ')
            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ل')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFEF9, 0xFEFA}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'إ')
            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ل')

        elif ord(c) in {0xFEF5, 0xFEF6}:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'آ')
            unlinked_text.insert(0, 'ل')



        else:

            unlinked_text.insert(0, c)

    return unlinked_text




def init():

    global current_char_index
    global text_buffer

    if bpy.context.object is None or bpy.context.object.type != 'FONT' or bpy.context.object.mode != 'EDIT':

        return
    
    text_buffer = swap_lines(bpy.context.object.data.body)
    text_buffer = unlink_text(text_buffer)
    
    addon_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    new_font = os.path.join(addon_dir, "bmonofont-i18n.ttf")
    
    if os.path.exists(new_font):
        bpy.context.object.data.font = bpy.data.fonts.load(new_font, check_existing=True)    

    bpy.context.object.data.align_x = 'RIGHT'
    
    current_char_index = 0
    
    update_visual_cursor_position()


#

def update_text():
    
    global text_buffer
    global current_char_index
    
    linked_text = link_text(text_buffer)
    linked_text = swap_lines(linked_text)
    
    bpy.ops.font.select_all()
    bpy.ops.font.delete()
    bpy.ops.font.text_insert(text=linked_text)
    
    update_visual_cursor_position()
    



def insert_text(char):
    
    global text_buffer
    global current_char_index
    
    text_buffer.insert(current_char_index, char)
    
    current_char_index += 1
    
    update_text()
    

def move_previous():
    
    global current_char_index
    
    if current_char_index > 0:

        current_char_index -= 1
    
        # update_text()
    
    update_visual_cursor_position()




def move_next():
    
    global text_buffer
    global current_char_index
    
    if current_char_index < len(text_buffer):
        
        current_char_index += 1
        
      
        
    update_visual_cursor_position()



def move_line_start():
    
    global text_buffer
    global current_char_index
    
    while current_char_index > 0:
        
        current_char_index -= 1
        
        if text_buffer[current_char_index] == '\n':
            
            current_char_index += 1

            break
        
    update_visual_cursor_position()




def move_line_end():
    
    global text_buffer
    global current_char_index
    
    while current_char_index < len(text_buffer):
        
        if text_buffer[current_char_index] == '\n':
            
            break
        
        current_char_index += 1
        
    update_visual_cursor_position()




def move_up():
    
    global text_buffer
    global current_char_index
    
    line_start = get_line_start()
    line_offset = current_char_index - line_start
    
    previous_line_end = line_start - 2
    
    previous_line_start = get_line_start(previous_line_end)
    
    previous_line_size = previous_line_end - previous_line_start
    
    new_index = previous_line_start + min(line_offset, previous_line_size + 1)
    
    if is_valid_char_index(new_index):
        
        current_char_index = new_index
        update_visual_cursor_position()




def move_down():
    
    global text_buffer
    global current_char_index
    
    new_line_size = 0
    
    line_start = get_line_start()
    line_offset = current_char_index - line_start
    
    new_index = get_next_line_start()
    
    if new_index == -1:
    
        return
    
    for i in range(line_offset):
        
        if not is_valid_char_index(new_index):
        
            break
        
        if text_buffer[new_index] == '\n':
        
            break
        
        new_index += 1
        
    if is_valid_char_index(new_index) or new_index == len(text_buffer):
        
        current_char_index = new_index
        update_visual_cursor_position()


def delete_previous():
    
    global current_char_index
    
    if current_char_index > 0:
        
        text_buffer.pop(current_char_index - 1)
        
        current_char_index -= 1
        
        update_text()

def delete_next():
    
    global text_buffer
    global current_char_index
    
    if is_valid_char_index(current_char_index):
        
        del(text_buffer[current_char_index])
        
        update_text()


#

def get_line_start(index=-1):
    
    global text_buffer
    global current_char_index
    
    line_start = current_char_index if index == - 1 else index
    
    while line_start > 0:
        
        line_start -= 1
        
        if text_buffer[line_start] == '\n':

            line_start += 1
            
            break
        
    return line_start


#

def get_next_line_start():
    
    global text_buffer
    global current_char_index
    
    next_line_start = current_char_index
    
    while next_line_start < len(text_buffer):
        
        if text_buffer[next_line_start] == '\n':

            next_line_start += 1
            
            break
        
        next_line_start += 1
        
        if next_line_start == len(text_buffer):
        
            return -1
        
    return next_line_start


#


def is_valid_char_index(index):
    
    if len(text_buffer) > 0 and index >= 0 and index < len(text_buffer):
    
        return True
    
    return False


def update_visual_cursor_position():
    
    global text_buffer
    global current_char_index


    
    for i in range(len(text_buffer)):
    
        bpy.ops.font.move(type='PREVIOUS_CHARACTER')
    
    #
    
    current_line_start = get_line_start()
    
    for i in range(current_line_start):

        if text_buffer[i] == '\n':
        
            bpy.ops.font.move(type='NEXT_LINE')
    

    bpy.ops.font.move(type='LINE_END')
    
    for i in range(current_line_start, current_char_index):

        
        if text_buffer[i] in {'ا', 'أ', 'إ', 'آ'}:
            
            if i > 0 and text_buffer[i - 1] == 'ل':
                
                continue
            
        bpy.ops.font.move(type='PREVIOUS_CHARACTER')

class HelloWorldOperatorBtn(bpy.types.Operator): 
    """Select the strip first. Write Arabic text. Then, press this button"""
    bl_idname = "wm.hello_world"
    bl_label = "Correct Text"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'} 
    text : bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Enter Arabic Text Here", default="")
    def execute(self, context):
        print("Hi World")
        myArobj = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.active_strip
        myArobj.text = link_text(myArobj.text) 
        return {'FINISHED'}
bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldOperatorBtn)
class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Arabic Text Correction"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type =  'SEQUENCE_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Strip'
    bl_context = "object"    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        cobjext = context.object
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("wm.hello_world")
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```